# Go to anchor without changing url

Tags: javascript, window, anchor

On loading a page I would like it to go to `#content` without changing the url.

I thought I would be able to use

```
window.location.hash = "content";
window.location.replace("#content", "");
```

but `#content` still exists on the url.

Any better method?

---

Edit:

Also tried

```
window.location.hash = "content";
window.location.replace(window.location.toString().replace("#content", ""));
```

But this sends the browser into a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could find the vertical position of the anchor with that id, and then scroll to that position.

Answer (score 6):

Go to or Scroll to anchor specified div id without changing url

[TRY DEMO](https://codepen.io/ProgrammingDIY/pen/XBvQQq)

```
function scrollSmoothTo(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'start',
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
#userdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  color: #337ab7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
<a onclick="scrollSmoothTo('userdiv')">
  Scroll to userdiv
</a>

<div id="userdiv">
  Lorem ipsum this is a random text
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a 10 year old question but I came across this issue when using Nextjs and wanted to smoothly navigate to a lower element without effecting the url... Nextjs, Typescript.

```
const Anchor: React.FC = () => {
    const smoothScrollTo = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const element = document.getElementById('search');
          element.scrollIntoView({
              block: 'start',
              behavior: 'smooth' // smooth scroll
          })
    };

 return (
   <div>
      <a
        href=""
        onClick={smoothScrollTo}>
        Let's go!
      </a>
      <div id = "search">Take me here!</div>
   </div>
  )
};
```

Now, it would probably be a best practice to be using refs here but this did exactly what I needed!  I'm sure other improvements can be made too!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it with a nice animation:

```
<a href="#link">Click to scroll</a>

<div id="link" style="margin-top: 1000px; height: 300px; background-color: blue; margin-bottom: 1000px">
    Click and scroll to this div without changing url!
</div>


<script>
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent default anchor click behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        if ($(hash).length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 300, function() {
                // Do something fun if you want!
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41wy9otd/2/)